# Neoclipse doesn't open db after Neo4j server upgrade from "1.9.4" to "2.0.0-M06"

Tags: neo4j, neoclipse

**Action:**

- upgraded Neo4j server from "1.9.4" to "2.0.0-M06" (Windows Vista OS + Java7 update 45)

---

**result:**

- Cannot open anymore the database in Neoclipse(1.9.1-win32 x86_64)
- Neo4j server "2.0.0-M06" graph (60 nodes) browsing is too slow (refreshed ~ each 1 sec)
- increse in CPU by ~10%.

Any hint?

**Neoclipse error:**

### > Database problem

> java.lang.RuntimeException:org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.CCifecycleExcption:
>   Component'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@2b885b8b'
>   was successfully initialized, but failed to start.

Comment: Neoclipse has not yet been upgraded to 2.0, can you share more information about your graph? We haven't experience a browser slowdown for 60 nodes so far.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. Before the database get bigger, does this means that it's not recommended to use both the actual version of NeoClipse (1.9.1) with Neo4j community server 2.0?                        ==> My db: 62 nodes, 73 properties, 125 relationships, 7 relationship types, 4 MB database disk usage,  0 MB logical log disk usage